# Youtube api v3 : Get Today's, Last week, last month, overall Most Viewed and Most Rated videos

Tags: php, youtube

Hello i'm using the youtube v3 api and i have these questions

1) When i'm make a call toy search.list function with this php code:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'maxResults' => 50,
  'order' => 'viewCount',
  'type'  => 'video'
));
```

the results will be the 50 MOST VIEWED videos OVERALL or today???

in any case i want to know how i can get MOST VIEWED videos for a specific time of period
(today, last week, last month, last 6 months).